# Why does HEAD~394 not work if I have 394 unpushed git commits?

Tags: git, diff, show, revision-history

I have the following alias:

```
unpushed== !GIT_CURRENT_BRANCH=$(git name-rev --name-only HEAD) && 
  git log origin/$GIT_CURRENT_BRANCH..$GIT_CURRENT_BRANCH --oneline
```

when I execute this with `|wc -l`, it tells me that I have 394 unpushed commits.
I use this number to run `git diff somecommitid HEAD~394`.
This fails with the following error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~394': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Strangely, it works right up until the number 358. In another clone, I have 478 commits, and git commands including `git show` work up until HEAD~411 and then fail.  Any clues?  I am using git 1.7.5.2 on debian linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best explanation I can think of is that the `~` operator doesn't follow branches.  It only includes the first parents.  If you want to refer to the last pushed commit, just use `origin/$GIT_CURRENT_BRANCH`.

Comment: I don't follow you.  My unpushed comand is using the current branch to get the number of commits. How would I use origin/$GIT_CURRENT_BRANCH in my git diff or git show commands please?

Comment: also, I am looking at UNpushed commits.

Comment: One more piece of data.  I can execute git show sha1 for the last version listed by the git unpushed command, so it is accessible in my clone.

Comment: You would use it like `git diff somecommitid origin/master`.  It doesn't matter if they're unpushed or not, because you're running the command on the local repo that knows about all the commits.  Git is very flexible about using commit ids anywhere, even if it's not from the currently checked out branch.  `origin/master` gets translated to its sha1 hash internally and uses your local copy of that commit to do the diff.

Comment: Thanks- any suggestions on how to translate the info I have to the info I need to run the command this way?  I have the number of unpushed commits from my unpushed alias.  How can I use this to get the commit id for the 394'th commit?

Comment: The only way I'm aware of to automate getting a specific number is to use your unpushed alias, but replacing `--oneline` with `--format="%h"`, then: `git unpushed | head -n 394 | tail -n 1`. Are you using this for some kind of report?  If so, I might be able to help better if you give me more details on the exact end result you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the diff between the remote branch and the common ancestor of the remote branch and your local branch (the common ancestor is the commit you were looking for with the HEAD~394 trick), you must obtain this common ancestor by using the merge-base subcommand. Then, you can see the diff using:

```
git diff $(git merge-base $GIT_CURRENT_BRANCH origin/$GIT_CURRENT_BRANCH) $GIT_CURRENT_BRANCH
```

The command will work in both cases when the branches **diverges** and when origin/$GIT_CURRENT_BRANCH is ancestor of $GIT_CURRENT_BRANCH

Also, if both branches diverges, you can see the diff of the "unpulled" changes by doing

```
git diff $(git merge-base $GIT_CURRENT_BRANCH origin/$GIT_CURRENT_BRANCH) origin/$GIT_CURRENT_BRANCH
```

Comment: what I am trying to see are all of the file diffs in the unpushed commits.  the common ancestor version does not match the 394'th version.